# Thread.Sleep implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was curious as to how `Thread.Sleep` was implemented. I had a look with Reflector for the implementation of `Thread.Sleep`. It calls the following function:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecurityCritical]
private static extern void SleepInternal(int millisecondsTimeout);
```

Does anyone know where that is defined? I am aware of other alternatives, such as Task.Delay. But was curious as to the actual implementation details.

Comment: `Sleep()` makes the thread sleep. If you want the thread to "do other stuff" and report back to you after n millisecs, look at timers instead.

Comment: The thread can/will continue doing work *when* it wakes up. In away a thread sleeping is similar to a human sleeping. An [extern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) method is implemented externally in this case it's a black-box provided by the .NET framework (in turn the framework will call the appropriate native function such as [WinAPI Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) or whatnot).

Comment: @John3136 I am aware of other alternatives, such as Task.Delay. But was curious as to the actual implementation details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joe Duffy's book Concurrent Programming provides all of the details you need. But to summarize:

- `Thread.Sleep` behaves similar to the Win API function [SleepEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx).
- A duration parameter = 0 will cause the current thread to yield to another with equal or higher priority.
- A duration parameter > 0 will cause a context switch and the current thread will remain in a Waiting state for until the specified amount of time has elapsed (approximately).
- The thread will remain in an alertable state which means it is allowed to process APC methods via [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx) and will respond to `Thread.Interrupt` calls.

I recommend poking through the SSCLI code for a more complete understanding of how it is implemented.

Regarding your question about not being able to reuse the thread for other work...I am a bit confused. `Thread.Sleep` is a voluntary suspension so you (the programmer) told the thread not to do any more work. And like I mentioned above the thread is said to be alertable so you could actually interrupt it or even force it to do work via APC methods.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18154164/158779) for more information about getting .NET threads to run APCs while `Thread.Sleep` is still pending.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep()` when called by a system thread (a real thread, not a user-thread) is a call that hooks into the OS kernel scheduling internals, similar to process sleep. It puts the execution context (that is visible at the kernel process level) into a "sleep" wait state so it consumes no CPU until it wakes up. It isn't a busy wait.

If you want it to be awake and/or doing other things, use some other mechanism besides `Thread.Sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `await Task.Delay()` if you want the thread to be reused

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am aware of it but was just wandering about the implementation details of `Thread.Sleep`