# Can this unexpected behavior of PrepareConstrainedRegions and Thread.Abort be explained?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadabortexception, cer

I was playing around with [Constrained Execution Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) tonight to better round out my understanding of the finer details. I have used them on occasion before, but in those cases I mostly adhered strictly to established patterns. Anyway, I noticed something peculiar that I cannot quite explain.

Consider the following code. Note, I targeted .NET 4.5 and I tested it with a Release build without the debugger attached.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool toggle = false;
        bool didfinally = false;
        var thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("running");
                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
                try
                {
                    while (true) 
                    {
                      toggle = !toggle;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    didfinally = true;
                }
            });
        thread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("sleeping");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("aborting");
        thread.Abort();
        Console.WriteLine("aborted");
        thread.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("joined");
        Console.WriteLine("didfinally=" + didfinally);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

What would you think the output of this program would be?

1. didfinally=True
2. didfinally=False

Before you guess read the documentation. I include the pertinent sections below.

> A constrained execution region (CER) is part of a mechanism for
>   authoring reliable managed code. A CER defines an area in which the
>   common language runtime (CLR) is constrained from throwing out-of-band
>   exceptions that would prevent the code in the area from executing in
>   its entirety. Within that region, user code is constrained from
>   executing code that would result in the throwing of out-of-band
>   exceptions. **The PrepareConstrainedRegions method must immediately
>   precede a try block and marks catch, finally, and fault blocks as
>   constrained execution regions.** Once marked as a constrained region,
>   code must only call other code with strong reliability contracts, and
>   code should not allocate or make virtual calls to unprepared or
>   unreliable methods unless the code is prepared to handle failures. **The
>   CLR delays thread aborts for code that is executing in a CER.**

and

> The reliability try/catch/finally is an exception handling mechanism
>   with the same level of predictability guarantees as the unmanaged
>   version. **The catch/finally block is the CER.** Methods in the block
>   require advance preparation and must be noninterruptible.

My particular concern right now is guarding against thread aborts. There are two kinds: your normal variety via `Thread.Abort` and then the one where a CLR host can go all medieval on you and do a forced abort. `finally` blocks are already protected against `Thread.Abort` to some degree. Then if you declare that `finally` block as a CER then you get added protection from CLR host aborts as well...at least I think that is the theory.

So based on what I think I know I guessed #1. It should print didfinally=True. The `ThreadAbortException` gets injected while the code is still in the `try` block and then the CLR allows the `finally` block to run as would be expected even without a CER right?

Well, this is not the result I got. I got a totally unexpected result. Neither #1 or #2 happened for me. Instead, my program hung at `Thread.Abort`. Here is what I observe.

- The presence of `PrepareConstrainedRegions` delays thread aborts inside `try` blocks.
- The absence of `PrepareConstrainedRegions` allows them in `try` blocks.

So the million dollar question is why? The documentation does not mention this behavior anywhere that I can see. In fact, most of the stuff I am reading is actually suggesting that you put critical uninterruptable code in the `finally` block specifically to guard against thread aborts.

Perhaps, `PrepareConstrainedRegions` delays normal aborts in a `try` block in addition to the `finally` block. But CLR host aborts are only delayed in the `finally` block of a CER? Can anyone provide more clarity on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cont'd from comments]

I will break my answer into two parts: CER and handling ThreadAbortException.

I don't believe a CER is intended to help with thread aborts in the first place; these are not the droids you're looking for. It's possible I'm misunderstanding the statement of the problem as well, this stuff tends to get pretty heavy, but the phrases I found to be key in documentation (admittedly, one of which was was actually in a different section than I mentioned) were:

`The code cannot cause an out-of-band exception`

and

`user code creates non-interruptible regions with a reliable try/catch/finally that *contains an empty try/catch block* preceded by a PrepareConstrainedRegions method call`

Despite not being inspired directly in the constrained code, a thread abort is an out-of-band exception. A constrained region only guarantees that, once the finally is executing, as long as it obeys the constraints it has promised, it will not be interrupted for managed runtime operations that would otherwise not interrupt unmanaged finally blocks. Thread Aborts interrupt unmanaged code, just as they interrupt managed code, but without constrained regions there *are* some guarantees and probably also a different recommended pattern for the behavior you may be looking for. I suspect this primarily functions as a barrier against thread suspension for Garbage Collection (probably by switching the Thread out of Preemptive garbage collection mode for the duration of the region, if I had to guess). I could imagine using this in combination with weak references, wait handles, and other low level management routines.

As for the unexpected behavior, my thoughts are that you did not meet the contract you promised by declaring the constrained region, so the result is not documented and should be considered unpredictable. It does seem odd that the Thread Abort would be deferred in the try, but I believe this to be a side-effect of unintended usage, which is only worth exploring further for academic understanding of the runtime (a class of knowledge that is volatile, since there is no guarantee of the behavior future updates could change this behavior).

Now, I'm not sure what the extent of said side effects are in using the above-mentioned in unintended ways, but if we exit the context of using the force to influence our controlling body and let things run the way they normally would, we do get some guarantees:

- A Thread.ResetAbort can, in some cases, prevent the abortion of a thread
- ThreadAbortExceptions can be caught; the entire catch block will run and, provided the abort is not reset, the ThreadAbortException will automatically be rethrown upon exiting the catch block.
- All finally blocks are guaranteed to run while a ThreadAbortException unwinds the callstack.

With that, here is a sample of techniques *meant* to be used in cases where abort resiliency is necessary. I have mixed multiple techniques in a single sample which are not necessary to use at the same time (generally you wouldn't) just to give you a sampling of options depending on your needs.

```
bool shouldRun = true;
object someDataForAnalysis = null;

try {

    while (shouldRun) {
begin:
        int step = 0;
        try {

            Interlocked.Increment(ref step);
step1:
            someDataForAnalysis = null;
            Console.WriteLine("test");

            Interlocked.Increment(ref step);
step2:

            // this does not *guarantee* that a ThreadAbortException will not be thrown,
            // but it at least provides a hint to the host, which may defer abortion or
            // terminate the AppDomain instead of just the thread (or whatever else it wants)
            Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
            try {

                // allocate unmanaged memory
                // call unmanaged function on memory
                // collect results
                someDataForAnalysis = new object();
            } finally {
                // deallocate unmanaged memory
                Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
            }

            Interlocked.Increment(ref step);
step3:
            // perform analysis
            Console.WriteLine(someDataForAnalysis.ToString());
        } catch (ThreadAbortException) {
            // not as easy to do correctly; a little bit messy; use of the cursed GOTO (AAAHHHHHHH!!!! ;p)
            Thread.ResetAbort();

            // this is optional, but generally you should prefer to exit the thread cleanly after finishing
            // the work that was essential to avoid interuption. The code trying to abort this thread may be
            // trying to join it, awaiting its completion, which will block forever if this thread doesn't exit
            shouldRun = false;

            switch (step) {
                case 1:
                    goto step1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    goto step2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    goto step3;
                    break;
                default:
                    goto begin;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

} catch (ThreadAbortException ex) {
    // preferable approach when operations are repeatable, although to some extent, if the
    // operations aren't volatile, you should not forcibly continue indefinite execution
    // on a thread requested to be aborted; generally this approach should only be used for
    // necessarily atomic operations.
    Thread.ResetAbort();
    goto begin;
}
```

I'm no expert on CER, so anybody please let me know if I've misunderstood. I hope this helps :)

Comment: You make some good points. I think most of my confusion stems from the documentation implying that the `try` block is NOT part of the CER. So why should we expect out-of-band exceptions to get delayed while the `try` block is executing. Normally you see empty `try` blocks immediately following `PrepareConstrainedRegions`. However, I like your point about "undefined behavior" in this scenario. I can definitely accept that as a reason. I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer as well.

Comment: Yeah, I actually thought I understood what was happening twice before I realized the whole of the situation was outside of the described context lol.

Answer (score 2):

I think I at least have a theory as to what is going on. If the `while` loop is changed to put the thread into an alertable state then the `ThreadAbortException` is injected even with a CER setup.

```
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
try
{
   // Standard abort injections are delayed here.

   Thread.Sleep(1000); // ThreadAbortException can be injected here.

   // Standard abort injections are delayed here.
}
finally
{
    // CER code goes here.
    // Most abort injections are delayed including those forced by the CLR host.
}
```

So `PrepareConstrainedRegions` will *demote* aborts issued from `Thread.Abort` while inside the `try` block so that it behaves more like `Thread.Interrupt`. It should be easy to see why this would make the code inside `try` a little safer. The abort is delayed until a point is reached where data structures are *more likely* to be in a consistent state. Of course, this assumes that a developer does not intentionally (or unintentionally for that matter) put the thread into an alertable state in the middle of updating a critical data structure.

So basically `PrepareConstrainedRegions` has the added undocumented feature of further constraining when aborts will get injected while inside a `try`. Since this feature is not documented it is prudent for developers to avoid relying on this assumption by not putting critical code in the `try` block of a CER construct. As documented only the `catch`, `finally`, and `fault` (not in C#) blocks are formally defined as the scoping of a CER.

Comment: I feel the "Constraints" section in the MSDN documentation on CERs adequately explains what is and isn't handled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx

Comment: @TheXenocide: If I read that right it tells you (the programmer) what cannot be done in a CER. I don't think it tells you what the behavior of a `try` block (which isn't technically part of the CER per the documentation) is. Did I miss something?

Comment: My answer started getting long and involved, so I just added a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your unexpected behavior is due to the fact that your code has the maximum reliability.

Define the following methods:

```
private static bool SwitchToggle(bool toggle) => !toggle;

[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState,Cer.Success)]
private static bool SafeSwitchToggle(bool toggle) => !toggle;
```

And use them instead of the body of your while cycle. You will notice that when calling SwitchToggle the cycle becomes abortable and when calling SafeSwitchToggle it is no more abortable.

The same goes if you add whichever other methods inside the try block that is not having a Consistency.WillNotCorruptState or Consistency.MayCorruptInstance.